# Parallax Scrolling scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I am needing a bit of help with parallax scrolling. I am trying to have an image stick to the bottom of the top div. Here is the jQuery

```
function parallax() {
var scrollPosition = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
jQuery('#grid').css('top', (0 - (scrollPosition * .5))+'px' );
}
```

Right now it is sticking to the top of the browser window when scrolled. I have used a higher number such as `jQuery('#grid').css('top', (134 - (scrollPosition * .5))+'px' );`

This gives me the proper spacing when the page loads but as soon as I scroll, white can be seen on top of the div. I am not to familiar with jQuery so any help would be appreciated.

Basically how can I assign the top position of the div to the variable `scrollPosition`.

/*** UPDATE ***/
Sorry, here are a some more details on the issue.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nunotmp/Bz9CY/)

See how is stick to the top of the window? I would like for it to stick to the bottom of the header.

Comment: How are you calling `parallax()`? is it, `$(window).on('scroll', parallax);`?

Comment: I am calling like so `jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function(e) {
  parallax();
 });
 `

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using `absolute` positioning. Change this to `fixed` and `top` should always be `0px`. That should sort your problem. Here's a [JSFiddle displaying it](http://jsfiddle.net/mzKp6/). No javascript is required to make it work.

Comment: Thanks you the comment. The position is fixed, but it is fixed to the browser window and not top of the div.

Comment: is the div fixed also? show some html and I'm sure we can sort it. Put it into the JSFiddle.

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle but this is not what I am trying to accomplish. I am trying to use parallax scrolling and not just fix the a top bar.

Comment: I see now, are you calling this parallax function every time the window is scrolled? like `$(window').scroll(function(){parallax();});`

Comment: The part where you do `(scrollPosition * .5)` is probably coming up with a `float`, where `top` needs to be an `integer`. Try wrapping this part with `Math.round();` So try `Math.round(scrollPosition * .5);`

Comment: Ok, I think I have it. Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzKp6/1/). I think you were subtracting where you needed to add

Comment: Here it [is updated](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz9CY/2/). The grid seems to be working okay, but `#home-para` appears to be hidden. It is moving though, when you inspect the element

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a new answer because I did not quite understand you before. You need the background to start at the bottom of the header, right?

I did this by forgetting about the absolute or fixed positioning, and the z-index. Instead I created a wrapper div, to wrap around everything after the #header div. The rest was fine, and no javascript was needed. The wrapper will automatically extend to the end of the page with the repeated background image.

Here it is:

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    padding:20px;
background: url('http://wpzombies.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/grid_bg.jpg') repeat top center;
}
```

remove the #grid div from css and html

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <h1>A header</h1>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="optin">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="home-para">
                <h2 class="home">Build, publish &amp; A/B test landing pages without I.T.</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, sapiente, magni qui ab vero repudiandae beatae a illum sed? Eaque, esse placeat incidunt laudantium sapiente debitis commodi rerum minus? Saepe.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, sapiente, magni qui ab vero repudiandae beatae a illum sed? Eaque, esse placeat incidunt laudantium sapiente debitis commodi rerum minus? Saepe.</p>
                <div id="opt-box">
                    <input type="email" /><a href="#" class="button orange">You can start here!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="space">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
</div>
```

And remove all js relating to the scroll function.

Here it [is in a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz9CY/3/).